# Type 'Document<any, any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'IAccount': _type, pai

Tags: typescript

I am not crystal clear on what this error is saying:

> Type 'Document<any, any, any>' is missing the following properties
> from type 'IAccount': _type, pai
>
> 47     return newAccount;

The error is in regards to this method:

```
async createAccount(
    dbSession: ClientSession,
    pai: string
  ): Promise<IAccount> {
    const newAccount = new this.Model(
      new (class implements IAccount {
        _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        _type: "Account" = "Account";
        pai = pai;
      })()
    );
    await newAccount.save(dbSession);
    return newAccount;
  }
```

I am also getting a related error that says:

> Overload 1 of 3, '(options?: SaveOptions | undefined):
> Promise<Document<any, any, any>>', gave the following error.
> Type 'ClientSession' has no properties in common with type 'SaveOptions'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(options?: SaveOptions | undefined,
> fn?: Callback<Document<any, any, any>> | undefined): void', gave the
> following error.
> Type 'ClientSession' has no properties in common with type 'SaveOptions'.   Overload 3 of 3, '(fn?: Callback<Document<any, any,
> any>> | undefined): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'ClientSession' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<Document<any, any, any>>'.
>
> 46     await newAccount.save(dbSession);

But it seems to be related to `AccountSchema` model which has an `any` in its angle brackets:

```
interface IAccount {
  _id: ID;
  _type: "Account";

  pai: string;
  disabledOn?: Date;
  tags?: ITag[];

  schemaVersion?: number;
  createdOn?: Date;
  updatedOn?: Date;
}

const AccountSchemaFields: Record<keyof IAccount, any> = {
  _id: Types.ObjectId,
  _type: { type: String, default: "Account" },

  pai: String,
  disabledOn: { type: Date, required: false },
  tags: { type: [TagSchema], required: false },

  schemaVersion: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  createdOn: Date,
  updatedOn: Date,
};
```

I feel like it's never a good rule to keep a type of `any` laying around, but not sure what to replace it with, if that is indeed the problem.

Or is this error saying that I am missing a Mongoose IAccount Document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually not using the types properly, for the `ClientSession` issue, this is because you are not passing `dbSession` as a `{session: dbSession}`

so the solution for that is

```js
 await newAccount.save({ session: dbSession});
```

while the second one, the error is straightforward, `newAccount` does not fully satisfy `IAccount`,

but you can circumvent this , by doing the below

```js
async function createAccount(
    dbSession: ClientSession,
    pai: string
  ): Promise<Pick<IAccount, '_id'>> {
    const newAccount = new Model(
      new (class implements IAccount {
        _id = Types.ObjectId();
        _type: "Account" = "Account";
        pai = pai;
      })()
    );
    await newAccount.save({session: dbSession});
    return newAccount
  }
```

Comment: when I implement your second solution, I get `Property 'pai' does not exist on type 'Pick<IAccount, "_id">'.

257           account.pai,` on a lot of other files with `account.pai` in it.

Comment: @Daniel, I will advise you assert all the callsite of `createAccount` to this `  (result as IAccount).pai`

that is.

`let result = await createAccount() as IAccount`